# What release of jQuery is compatible with jQuery UI 1.8.23

Tags: jquery

I couldn't find this info on jquery blog. Please share any info reg this.

I am using jquery1.7.2, so just want to make sure jQuery UI 1.8.23 is compatible with jquery1.7.2

Comment: http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/08/jquery-ui-1-8-23/ was the first result of a Google search.

Comment: @Blazemonger, thanks for your comment, but the blog doesn't list down all the compatible jQuery versions, it just mentions about jquery1.8

Comment: From the jQuery-UI homepage, then: "v1.9.2 (is compatible with) jQuery 1.6+", which would logically imply that v1.8.23 is as well.

Comment: You are assuming that.. that is not good. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI provides exact compatibility list with all versions of jquery.

Comment: I am deducing it, not assuming it. And I'm correct, so why are you criticizing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI

it is compatible with jquery `1.3.2+`

```
August 15, 2012   - 1.8.23  -   1.3.2+
```